# Show nth value in a list that matches specific criteria [EXCEL]

Tags: excel, list, search, indexing, match

I would like to find the nth value in a list that matches specific criteria and have those values printed in separate places in separate worksheets.

More specifically I have a list of invoice numbers either beginning with a number or with PF and I want the first (or second, third etc) value beginning with PF to show on the Proforma Invoice worksheet, and the first (or second, third etc) value beginning with a number to show on the Invoice worksheet.

At the moment I have a selection of invoice numbers like so:

**Invoice #**

```
PF17-0982

43256

65342

96038

PF16-0934

10293
```

And I would like to print the nth value on this list matching the criteria I give, so either beginning in a number or beginning in PF, in a separate worksheet.

Initially I tried

```
=IF(LEFT('Top Sheet'!S5)="P",'Top Sheet'!S5,"")
```

which works to find the number beginning with PF but obviously only for the first cell in the list. 
I also have

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT('Top Sheet'!S5)*1),'Top Sheet'!S5,"")
```

Which again works wonderfully for the first value in the list but not for much else.

So, naturally, I googled and tried using INDEX and MATCH and SEARCH functions as found here https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-match-cell-contains but I don't want the output to be another list dependant on only one of the values in the invoice number list. However I don't mind having an intermediate list (e.g. list of TRUE and FALSE values) which will ultimately lead to me having a single output. I have this list at the moment which was done using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"PF"},'Top Sheet'!S5)))>0
```

And that brings me here, I've tried various variations of the above techniques and failed hopelessly. I either get an error of some description or just TRUE and FALSE values. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: have you considered filtering the list with PivotTable (or Power Query), or you need the filtered list to be dynamic?

Comment: Hi, could you expand on that a little? I'm not familiar with PivotTable or Power Query. Also, thanks for the edit haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another formula approach, with which you can enter the formula normally, is to use the `AGGREGATE` function to determine the row number within the array of invoices.  With the `SMALL` operator, you can work on an array, ignore errors, and return multiple values.

If `Invoices` is a named range containing your list of invoices, then:

- For invoices starting with `PF`

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Invoices,AGGREGATE(15,6, 1/(LEFT(Invoices,2)="PF")*ROW(Invoices)-MIN(ROW(Invoices))+1,ROWS($1:1))),"")
  ```
- For invoices starting with a digit

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Invoices,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(-LEFT(Invoices,1)*ROW(Invoices))*ROW(Invoices)-MIN(ROW(Invoices))+1,ROWS($1:1))),"")
  ```

For either of these formulas, enter in some cell and fill down until the formula returns blanks.  The `ROWS...` argument will increment and return the appropriate `k` for the `SMALL` function.

Another method would be to use a simple Filter, then copy/paste the visible cells to where you want.

Or you could use the Advanced Filter, which has a built-in method to paste the results to another location.

Comment: I'm struggling to make this work atm, but useful to not have to do crtl+shift+enter especially when explaining to other people in the office.

I am trying to avoid the copy-paste options as I would like all my worksheets to be populated by the top sheet.

Comment: @Ella what part are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi, seems to be working now, no idea what I did wrong first time round, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to extract multiple items from a list you can use the INDEX function with SMALL to create an array formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$B$9,SMALL(IF((ISNUMBER($B$4:$B$9)),ROW($B$4:$B$9)-3),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

IMPORTANT: use **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** when entering this formula to make it an array formula.

This formula takes the first numeric value from your list.  If the formula is changed to ROW(2:2) it would select the 2nd numeric value from the list and you can autofill the formula down to extract as many as you like.

It's quite a complicated formula to follow but you first index a range "INDEX(B4:B9" then use SMALL with an if statement "(ISNUMBER(B4:B9)".  Then define the first row of the source data "ROW(B4:B9)-3)" the minus 3 is because it's 3 rows from the top.  Next the row that matches your criteria that you want to extract "ROW(1:1)" and last the column that contains the value that you want "),1"

I'm not the best person to explain this formula but there are some good tutorials online.

[image: Example with formula in F4]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Gordon!

This works to extract the numbers and is much better than anything I could have come up with alone, I will play around with it for the entries beginning in PF (which will hopefully help me understand how it all works).

Comment: Thanks, you should be able to use LEFT($B$4:$B$9,2)="PF". Also if you want to use more than 1 criteria use "*" as an "AND"(criteria 1)*(criteria 2) and confusingly the "+" can be used for "OR".  It's not easy.  I still have to copy it from somewhere I've used it before as I can't write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

PivotTable alternative:

- (optional) select the range of cells including the header "Invoice #" cell
- `Insert` tab > `PivotTable`
- make sure the header cell is included in the `Table/Range:` field
- select `Existing Worksheet` and the `Location` range where you want the filtered list
- on the `PivotTable Field List` that shows up on the right check the `Invoice #` field
- on the sheet, in the `Row Labels` cell click on the triangle filter button and select `Label Filters` > `Begins With...` > `PF`
- (optional) in the `Design` tab click `Grand Totals` > `Off for Rows and Columns`, uncheck `Column Headers`, and rename the `Row Labels` cell text if needed

For the numbers, you can copy the PivotTable and change the Label Filter to `Less Than...` > `A`

Whenever the source `Invoice #` range changes, you can click `Refresh All` on the `Data` tab for the PivotTables to refresh.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm not sure it's what I need for this but interesting none-the-less!